# Typealias must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, public, functor, type-alias

I'm implementing a basic `Functor`

```
// class Functor f where
public protocol Functor {
    typealias A
    typealias B
    typealias FB

    // fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    func fmap(f: A -> B) -> FB
}

public struct Box<X> {
    let value: X

    public init(value v: X) {
        value = v
    }
}

extension Box : Functor {
    public typealias A = X
    public typealias B = Any
    public typealias FB = Box<B>

    public func fmap(f: A -> B) -> FB {
        return FB(value: f(value))
    }
}
```

If I don't declare `public typealias`, an error will popup

> Typealias must be declared public because it matches a requirement in
>   public protocol

That message does not give much clue, why does it need to be public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All members of a protocol must have the same access as that protocol. Because of this requirement, all members implicitly are set to the same access level.

Your `typealias` problem must be a bug is Swift. The `typealias` should implicitly be public, just like `func fmap(_)` is public.

[Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

> **The access level of each requirement within a protocol definition is automatically set to the same access level as the protocol**. You cannot set a protocol requirement to a different access level than the protocol it supports. This ensures that all of the protocol’s requirements will be visible on any type that adopts the protocol.
>
> > NOTE
> >
> > If you define a public protocol, the protocol’s requirements require a public access level for those requirements when they are implemented. This behavior is different from other types, where a public type definition implies an access level of internal for the type’s members.